# How to pause on a line of code, and only continuing when a button is pressed?

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is have a loop, and for each time it loops I would like to

1) Change a TextView's text according to what x is
2) Take an EditText's text and set it into an ArrayList

And the loop should not continue unless I click a button, meaning that the program waits for the user to click a button before continuing the code, and all this is in a loop.

I would prefer not to use threads because of past troubles with it, so if there is any other way I would welcome it

Comment: Why do you need a loop? You just want to do something when you click a button, but in the meanwhile you are doing what?

Comment: @Gio The reason why I have a loop is so that instead of repeatedly putting the same code in the button onclicklistener, I can use loops instead to loop through the same code

Comment: That does not make sense, @user154989. If the loop only does it once for each click, why not just "do it once" on each click? Why is a loop needed?

Comment: @Xabster A loop is needed so the variables change accordingly, so instead of having one onclicklistener for x, then one for x+1, then one for x+2, I can use a loop instead and only use "x" and it'll increment accordingly

Comment: Sorry, I think you will need to use threads.  You can't have the main thread (the UI thread) wait for a button, since you're not supposed to block that thread.  See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), scroll down to the section on Threads.

Comment: I think you could achieve this differently. Why not use a single onclick that calls a handler that takes the view and an identifier (enum) that would let you know what to do with what.

Comment: Yes, this is just not how android works.  Android is event driven, so you really should turn your thinking inside out and write code which advances state on each event. Alternatively you can run your loop on a background thread and wait for the UI thread to signal that events have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in your problem

```
the loop should not continue unless I click a button, meaning that the program waits for the user to click a button before continuing the code, and all this is in a loop.
```

why dont you just put your code in the `onClickListener` it will do the same thing rather than pausing the execution of code which is pointless.

```
List editTextValue=new ArrayList();

button.setOnClickListener(){

   textView.setText(x);
   editTextValue.add(editText.getText());

}
```

in the above snippet it is doing what you want to achieve. it set the `textView's text` and and the `editText value` in a `arraylist` as soon as the button is `clicked`.

Comment: The thing is, it must be in a loop

Comment: why would it have to be a loop?

Comment: its just how the code works, rather than putting 10+ onclicklisteners, I would much rather have a loop, which runs 10 times and does the same thing. Shorter code basically, but "slightly" more complicated

Comment: My bad, its not 10+ onclicklisteners, its 10+ if statements inside the onclicklisteners. I also want it to be defined by the user, and not by myself, so that's why I have to use a loop to loop a certain amount of times to match what the user wants.

Comment: could you post an example of what you mean by if statements and defined by the user.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why a loop is a really bad idea. Specially if you will just do things just after a touch or each iteration. Android was not designed to work like that. As everyone else has told you, you need to approach this issue with an event. You need to do something like:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
int x = 0;
```

Then

```
button.setOnClickListener(){
    textView.setText(x);
    list.add(editText.getText());
    x++;
}
```

Sorry if i cant expand my answer, but I'm on my phone.